# C++ how to load a pre defined object using #include from a .hpp file

Tags: c++, object, include, header-files

I am wanting to generate random data and store it in an hpp file so that I can then include and access it in another file. For Example:

random_data.hpp

```
uint32_t input[] = { 938, 916, 829, 803, 284, 796, 357}
```

Now if I include the file random_data.hpp, I can directly use the array "input".

```
#include "random_data.hpp";
printf(input.size()); //Do somthing
```

I am trying to generate the hpp file for a object. I was trying to write it by hand in a file but im having trouble on formatting. Is there a better-way to generate it? using std::out?

The object I am tring to currently make is of type Node:

```
class XY{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
}

Node{
public:
    std::vector< XY > xy;
    std::vector< std::string > name;
}
```

What is a good way to generate this data/file? And what format would the hpp file be in if manually typed, I have tried:

```
Node input = { {{1,2},{3,4}}, {'BOB','JOE'} }
```

Comment: Unrelated: It looks like you're trying to learn C++ by trial and error. This is a very, very slow route to competence, let alone mastery. I recommend grabbing [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and working your way past simple bugs before you try to write too much more.

Comment: One technique is to use a Singleton (search the internet for "C++ singleton thread safe").

Comment: Another technique is to declare the variable as global in a cpp file, then make an `extern` declaration in the header file.

Comment: Finally, consider throwing the data into a file.  This technique will allow you to change the data without having to recompile your program.